# Lifetime estimate of components where only a fraction of them have failed so far?

Tags: survival, reliability, kaplan-meier

I am attempting to calculate how long a component is expected to last and ultimately how many working components will be left at a future point in time.

800 have failed and 2200 are still working. I have calculated the Kaplan Meier estimator, but this does not give me the full survivor function as many components are working longer than the longest lifetime of the failed components.

I was planning to do a Monte Carlo based on the Kaplan-Meier estimator. With this I can calculate the future life of components younger than the longest failure time. But how to calculate the values for the older components? Or the total count of surviving components in the future?

Is there any alternative methods to calculate estimated lifetimes of components and/or the total count of working components in the future?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a parametric approach instead. You would have to pick a parametric distribution family and use the data to fit the parameters. Once you find the parameters (and after checking if they make sense) you can use that to find the estimated remaining useful life function and an estimated reliability function